# Transition between Background-attachment: 'fixed' and 'scroll'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a textured background, and I want it so the background scrolls for a little bit, but then becomes fixed *at the point* where it switches. So, right now my code is:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop()>110){
     $('body').css('background-attachment', 'fixed');
  }else{
     $('body').css('background-attachment', 'scroll');
  }
});
```

When it passes the point where it activates, the background becomes fixed as though it has always been fixed, meaning there is a noticeable "jump" to its original position. Is there anyway I can have it so the background texture sticks to the position where it has scrolled down to, and stays that way? Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `background-position`:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop()>110){
     $('body').css('background-attachment', 'fixed')
              .css('background-position', '0px -110px');
  }else{
     $('body').css('background-attachment', 'scroll')
              .css('background-position', '0px 0px');
  }
});
```